# Glassfish on Eclipse. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I follow this tutorial (http://serendipstick.blogspot.com/2011/01/setup-eclipse-jee6-primefaces-and.html), and I cannot install Glassfish. Here is the situation:

I'm here: "Now let's start eclipse and install some plugins...."
and
" 3) Glassfish integration via Servers tab, add new server, Download additional server adapters, Oracle Glassfish Server Tools."
Everything works great until I press "Finish". There is an error:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Problems downloading artifact: 
org.eclipse.update.feature,oracle.eclipse.tools.juno.glassfish,2.0.1.201201241920.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8df101dee12517a86fe92bf6644cd44f and found fbef299b507f02fcab8887c108e82434.
```

Could You tell me what is going on? How can I install Oracle Glassfish Server Tools?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem today. I tried to install GlassFish server adapter through "New server wizard" in my Eclipse Juno IDE. During download/install procedure i got the same error message as you did.

Problem was solved by going to Help -> Install New Software... and entering this site location: http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno. Be sure to check *Oracle GlassFish Server Tools* option.